# Changing the font type in plot(varImp())

Tags: r, plot

How can I change the font type ion a `varImp` plot? I can use `family` option in other plots to change font type in r plots. However, it does not work when I type them in a varImp plot.

```
plot(varImp(...), family="serif")
```

Comment: Whether the `varImp` is from `caret` package?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rtemis/versions/0.79/topics/dplot3.varimp), you can do:

```
dplot3.varimp(varimp, font.family = "Open Sans", font.size = 14, font.color = "000")
```

If that doesn't work, try taking a look at these similar questions:

- [How to change font family in a legend in an R-plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136990/how-to-change-font-family-in-a-legend-in-an-r-plot)
- [How to change font family in this R plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552772/how-to-change-font-family-in-this-r-plot)